# DirectX11 Vertices behind getting drawn in front

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

I've been following a few Rastertek tutorials and I've come accross an issue, where the vertices are not being drawn properly.  Vertices behind are being drawn in front of the vertices that should be in front.  I'm not sure why this is happening, as I believe that everything is set up correctly.

[image]

[image]

Here is my depth stencil:

```
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC dsd;
    ZeroMemory(&dsd, sizeof(dsd));

    dsd.DepthEnable = true;
    dsd.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    dsd.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

    dsd.StencilEnable = true;
    dsd.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
    dsd.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

    dsd.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsd.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    dsd.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsd.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    dsd.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsd.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    dsd.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsd.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    DXHRes(mDevice->CreateDepthStencilState(&dsd, &mDepthStencilState));
    mContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(mDepthStencilState, 1);
```

What would be a cause of this and what section should I be looking at?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing jumps out as a likely cause. Did you try a graphics debugger like [VSGD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125501.aspx)?  You can inspect the incorrectly drawn pixels and see why they're passing / failing.

Comment: Do you have a depth buffer?

Comment: Yes, the depth buffer is created just before the stencil state

Comment: It actually looks like you're doing depth *exactly* backwards, i.e. the furthest drawn pixel is always on top.  Are you using some unusual transformations in your vertex shader?  Conceptually, the depth buffer usually starts at `1.0`, passes pixels `LESS` than the current value, with the `0.0` plane being closest to the screen.  Did you somehow get that backwards?

Comment: It would appear that I have incorrectly set my view matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. I didn't incorrectly set up any device resources (to my knowledge).

For anyone else having the same problem, I was incorrectly setting my view matrix every frame.  Make sure that your cameras view matrix is being properly set (such as properly setting XMMatrixLookAtLH')